# Сравнение списков

Tags: python

Как произвести сравнение списков на эквивалентность, то бишь
"мама мыла раму" будет эквивалентно "мыла раму мама". Я так понимаю циклом проходить и сравнивать с каждым элементом списка. Или есть более изящные варианты?

Comment: хватит сортировки обоих списков и их сравнения..

Comment: А будут ли эквиваленты списки `['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']` и `['мыла', 'раму', 'мама', 'мыла']` (2 раза повторяется строка `'мыла'`)? Если да, то через сравнение множеств (`set`).

Comment: @nomnoms12 идея хорошая, но мне кажется, что нет

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от того, интересует вас поэлементное сравнение или просто сравнение элементов списка как таковых можно написать так:

```
lst1=['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']
lst2=['мыла', 'раму','мама']
if set(lst1)==set(lst2):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

либо так:

```
if lst1==lst2:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: Как-то Вы усложнили процесс: `print(set(lst1) == set(lst2))` и `print(lst1 == lst2)`.

Comment: Я просто его аккуратно описал, что бы ТС мог полять что к чему, а уж дальше - явно оптимизировать описанный подход для своих нужд.